# How can I assign a value to a number of different variables in a collection using loops?

Tags: vb.net, loops, variables, reference, containers

I have a problem that has been bugging me for a while now. Consider this code:

```
    Public Class Class1

        Dim VariableList as New List(of Object) From {MainForm.X, MainForm.Y,
     SettingsForm.Z, SettingsForm.Textbox1.Text} '...etc.

    Sub SetToZero()
        For Each Element in VariableList
            Element = 0
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub SetToCustomValue(value As Double)
        For Each Element in VariableList
            Element = value
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub LoadValuesFromFile()
        Dim path As String = MainForm.GetPath()

        For Each Element in VariableList
            Element = File.Readline()
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub SaveValuesToFile()
        Dim path As String = MainForm.GetPath()

        For Each Element in VariableList
            Element = File.Writeline()
        Next
    End Sub


    'and more similar functions/subs
```

As you can see, what this class does is that it takes lot of different variables from different places into a collection, and then various functions read or write values to every variable in that collection using loops. In this example, I have just a few variables, but most of the time there are dozens.

Reading the values is not a problem. Writing them, is, because when I declare that VariableList at the top of my class, that List just makes a copy of each variable, rather than maintaining a reference to it. Meaning that if, say, one of the functions modifies the MainForm.X in that List, the actual variable MainForm.X is not modified. To work with references, I would have to forgo loops, and assign every single variable manually, in every function. Which is obviously a lot of bad code. I want to declare that list of variables only once, and then use loops, like in this example code that I wrote above. My question is, how can I make such a container (List, Array, whatever) that would retain the references to the original variables in it, and make the code above possible?

Comment: Consider a static class that has the list as a public property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static

Comment: Are you trying to use the variables as if they were untyped? The use of Object here seems to point that way. If it's the case, the follow-up subs will be exposed to a lot of errors as they don't test for the type.

Comment: NoChance - thanks, what would the Static class, as well as the list as public property change here? I am not sure I follow the logic.
Laancelot, I just thought Object is a reference type, so it would automatically retain references to these variables... They don't, really. My mistake. So I'm okay with Double or String.

Comment: If you never read about T, I suggest you give it a try, you might just find something that interests you. T is a generic type, which permits you some nice tricks once you get the hand of it. It kinda advanced, though.

Comment: Thank you, I will, but what about the original question of my post?

Comment: _"I just thought Object is a reference type, so it would automatically retain references to these variables"_ - `Object` is a reference type, yes, but it is _**not**_ a reference _pointer_. Its purpose is not to hold pointers to other variables/objects, but it represents the very base of an actual, _**separate**_ object. In your code, those variables' values will be copied before being boxed in an `Object` as they need to be put on the _Heap_ (where reference types live) instead of on the _Stack_ (where value types live).

Comment: Thank you for clarification, Vincent. Could you please tell me how can I do that last part, so that my code would work in the way I described?

Comment: Unfortunately what you're trying to do isn't fully straightforward, but it is possible. Your best bet is to look into reflection, specifically [`Type.GetProperty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_). It allows you to get a property by name and, using the resulting [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo), get/set it on the object instance.

Comment: To do this you also need keep track of _which_ object to call it on. I recommend using a [`KeyValuePair(Of Object, PropertyInfo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2) and storing that in your list instead, where `Object` is the object which to call the property on (ex. `MainForm`) and `PropertyInfo` is the property which to get/set.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to store pointers to variables in VB.NET. As a workaround, you can use a class to store your variables, as a class is always used as a pointer.

Here's an example of a way to achieve this with a `ContainerClass` which own a Dictionary of integers. One interest of this method would be that you can declare and name "variables" dynamically. In reality, they will be managed `KeyValuePair`. Once you have instantiated a copy of this class, you can use it to "manage" your variables by using this class as your pointer.

I included a loop which set all the integers to the same number just for fun, and to demonstrate the kind of manipulation which would end up having an effect similar to one of those described in your question.

```
Public Class Form2
    'This is the container class which will be used to bypass the lack of pointers
    'if you wanted to change a property, like the window width, it would be more difficult, but simples variables will be no trouble
    Private variableContainer As New VariableContainer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        variableContainer.AddVar("X", 5)
        variableContainer.AddVar("Y", 15)

        Debug.Print(variableContainer.GetVar("X"))
        Debug.Print(variableContainer.GetVar("Y"))

        variableContainer.SetAllVar(42)
        Debug.Print("Next line will print 42")
        Debug.Print(variableContainer.GetVar("X"))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class VariableContainer
    'I know a public variable wouldn't need the fancy functions down there, but it's usually better to encapsulate, especially if you're working with a team
    'and "future you" count as a teammate, never forget that...
    Private list As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    Public Sub AddVar(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As Integer)
        list.Add(name, value)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetVar(ByVal name As String) As Integer
        If list.ContainsKey(name) Then
            Return list(name)
        Else
            'I choose -1 arbitrarily, don't put too much thinking into this detail
            Return -1
        End If
    End Function

    Public Sub SetVar(ByVal name As String, ByVal num As Integer)
        If list.ContainsKey(name) Then
            list(name) = num
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetAllVar(ByVal num As Integer)
        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

        For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In list
            dict.Add(item.Key, num)
        Next

        list = dict
    End Sub
End Class
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you, laancelot, I have tested this code by calling it such as this:         `Class1.AddToTheList(MainForm.X, MainForm.Y)
        Class1.SetToArbitraryNumber(42)
        Debug.Print(MainForm.X)`
And unfortunately, it prints 0, meaning it didn't set the MainForm.X variable... Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I'm willing to walk with you through this explanation, but I'll need more context. Please pastebin me the whole code and I'll check it out. I think it's quite simple, I just don't want to say the wrong thing.

Comment: Thank you, laancelot. Here is the code I used to test your solution independently: [link](https://pastebin.com/TsmMQqwe). It prints 0 when I run it.

Comment: Haha I didn't see that one coming! The problem is... kinda the same thing. I didn't though you would use `AddToTheList` for references, so I used a `For Each` loop, which will not use reference. [I modified your past](https://pastebin.com/1i1Mfk9A) to reflect my new understanding of what you were trying to achieve. The important thing to notice here is the `ByRef` in `Sub AddToTheList(ByRef num As Integer)`; it's the opposite of `ByVal`. Are you familiar with the difference between the two?

Comment: As an unrelated note, I suggest you start using `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On`. These settings will help you avoid many mistakes and better understand what you're doing, and as a bonus your code will not only work better but also be more readable.

Comment: Thanks, laancelot, and yes, I do know the difference... And indeed, I am trying to get this to work ByRef. I tested your modified code, and it still prints 0, though... Does it print 42 to you? I am confused.

Comment: I see. I made a mistake and now I lost you some time, I'm sorry about it. 

Now: there's no way to use pointers in VB, not like you can do in C++ or the like. I miss my pointers. VB manages the code "behind your back", it tries to make things easier for you but at the same time it takes some control away from you. So, even though you can't make new pointers, you can use the ones that VB creates. Although VB will not deal with variables as if they were pointers, it will deal with classes as references. As you can guess, you can then use a class as a workaround. I'll cook you an example...

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you spend your own time to help me out. I just hope there is some kind of solution to this problem. I will be waiting for that example you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have kids and... well sometimes it makes short delays relatives! [Here's another pastebin](https://pastebin.com/rJ32mKSY) for your trouble. As I mentioned, VB.NET don't like the kind of logic which you are trying to setup, so we'll have to work around these limitations. So here's a method: I set up a class which remembers variables for you. It cannot point to existing variables, but you can work the other way around and even create variables dynamically (which wouldn't be feasible easily either).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write that code, laancelot. Don't worry about the delays, I can wait. I think I understand what you wrote, but I'm not seeing these X or Y being declared as variables in the Form1. Thing is, I do need to declare them in a usual way (like `Dim X as Integer`), because they will be needed to be accessed and modified like any other variable in my application, even apart from this new class that I'm trying to make work. Are you saying that this is impossible in VB.NET?

Comment: It is indeed, well, not exactly impossible, but very hard. Visual Vincent suggested it could be done with reflection, which seems realistic, but that's very advanced stuff - even hardened programmers are not often at ease with that kind of coding. What I did was to encapsulate the variables in another class, which permits tu use that class as a makeshift pointer. You have to understand that VB.NET don't want us to be able to store a variable's pointer. That is the exact problem with your question. My method is but a workaround, where I declare X into the variable which is owned by the Form.

Comment: While I did everything dynamically, you could hard-code any variable you know you will use in the variable container class, but unless you set it up inside a container (like a List or a Dictionary) you won't be able to iterate through it.

Comment: `Thing is, I do need to declare them in a usual way (like Dim X as Integer), because they will be needed to be accessed and modified like any other variable in my application` You know, instantiating a class which contains your variables is just one step more than just declaring them. To illustrate what I mean, look at this: `variableContainer.AddVar("X", 5)` is functionally the same. You can access this "variable" from the same places you would access X, except that I coded a method to do so (to avoid further problems if it's mishandled).

Comment: Thank you, laancelot. I will try to implement this, but it will mean re-writing half of my application - tens of thousands of lines of code, often changing the very logic of it. Damn, this is unfortunate. I should have gone with C++ instead...

Comment: If you want to learn a new language, C# supports pointers, and it's less brutal than C++ for someone coming from VB.NET. Also, you'll probably have more job opportunities with C# than C++, although C++ has some really nice things.

Comment: I did some minor projects with C#... Thank you, that's good advice. I will switch to C# soon.